# Firebase cannot connect to server

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to connect my app to Firebase. I followed the steps on doing this. I created a project in Firebase. I downloaded the Google services.info file. I put my pod file in the project. The project runs in Xcode but it will not allow me to connect to my 
Firebase project to the server.

Below is what error message I am getting. I even cleared my cache in Safari but nothing seems to work. In my app delegate is were I am trying to test my project to see if it is detected in Firebase database. Below is the error I am receiving in the Xcode console.

```
":ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not access bucket sya2-moments-1e2c9.appspot.com. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."
  }
}, "
```

Code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        let dummyUser = User(uid: "123", username: "myUserNameDummy", bio: "My Dummy User", fullName: "My Dummy User", website: "My Dummy User", follows: [], followedBy: [], profileImage: UIImage(named: "1"))
        dummyUser.save { (error) in
            print(error)
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check your Rules in your firebase. If you want to write and read data from your firebase Server then change it to "true" like the image bellow.

[image]

and for storage like this :

[image]

add the following code to safe something to your firebase in your case a user :

```
var db: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    db = Database.database().reference()
    //        checkForPrivacy()

}

self.db.child("key").setValue(dummyUser, withCompletionBlock: {error ,ref in
    if error != nil{
          print("error")
    }else{
        print("ok")
    }
})
```

Comment: import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    var db: DatabaseReference!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        db = Database.database().reference()
        //        checkForPrivacy()
        
    }
    
    self.db.child("key").setValue(dummyUser, withCompletionBlock: {error ,ref in
    if error != nil{
    print("error")
    }else{
    print("ok")
    }
    })return true
        }

Comment: I put in app delegate I get errors Method does not override any method from its superclass, Value of type 'UIResponder' has no member 'viewDidLoad'